# Trying to insert data from sql to cookies

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

Trying to insert multiple "ids" into cookie from mysql database. So, i am  pressing a few links and collect their ids in an array. And then trying to implode this array and give it to a function, which should take an info from sql database and write it down to cookie $basket.
But in showbasket.php i've got only one, last pressed id. The main problem is in ids i think, but i can't figure it out.

p.s. this is just a cookie-training, not a real implementation.

this is a file add2basket.php:

```
<?php

   require 'functions.php';

   $id = $_GET['id'];

   $arr = [];
   $arr[]=$id;
   $ids = implode(",", $arr); 

 save2basket($ids); 
 header("Location: catalog.php");
?>
```

This is a function save2basket:

```
function save2Basket($ids){
     global $conn, $basket, $ids;

     if(!isset($_COOKIE['basket']))
     $basket = setcookie('basket', $sel);


     $sql = "SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE id IN ($ids)";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

     $select = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            mysqli_free_result($result);
     $sel = base64_encode(serialize($select));
     $basket = setcookie('basket', $sel);
}
```

This is a showbasket.php file:

```
   <?php

   $basket = unserialize(base64_decode($_COOKIE['basket']));
   print_r($basket);
```

Comment: Display the value of $id here

Comment: $id is an integer, and in $ids the same.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your PHP code with below code. You should have to save your selected ids in session. Currently each time php page will called your array will be initialized blank and it will contain only recent id. Don't forget to unset session after your entire operation get complete.

```
<?php
   session_start();
   require 'functions.php';

   $id = $_GET['id'];

   $_SESSION['arr'] = $id;
   $ids = implode(",", $_SESSION['arr']); 

 save2basket($ids); 
 header("Location: catalog.php");
?>
```